# Genus des substantivisch gebrauchten Indefinitpronomens "andere" (z.B. "Weil die/der andere abgelenkt war")

Tags: indefinite-pronoun

Das Bundesamt für Verkehr und Digitale Infrastruktur (BMVI) schreibt auf [neue Autobahnplakate](https://www.dvr.de/presse/presseinformationen/laufen-lernen-dvr-und-bmvi-praesentieren-neue-autobahnplakate):

> Weil die andere kurz abgelenkt war

und

> Weil der andere zu schnell war

Wie sind diese Sätze grammatisch zu verstehen?  Besonders das Wort "andere"?  Sind diese Sätze grammatisch vollständig?

Scheinbar ist *andere* hier kein Nomen, oder es wäre *die/der Andere*.  Auf Englisch ist *other* [ein Nomen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/other#Noun).  Und scheinbar kann es entweder *der* oder *die andere* sein, obwohl das grammatische Geschlecht auf Deutsch nicht mit dem natürlichen Geschlecht übereinstimmen muss (Vergleich: *sie ist jemand, der gerne singt*).

Wenn ich [das Wikipedia-Artikel über Indefinitpromonen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinitpronomen) richtig verstehe, ist *andere* hier ein Indefinitpronomen, das als Substantiv gebraucht wird — genauso wie *jemand*.

Wann kann ein Indefinitpronomen ein Artikel bekommen?  Und wie wird das Genus bestimmt?  Ändert sich das denn doch, im Gegensatz zu "jemand", nach dem natürlichen Geschlecht?

Vielleicht ist es ähnlich bei "der eine" / "die eine"?

Comment: Hätte auch gesagt, dass *Andere* großgeschrieben werden muss. Kenne die besagte Plakataktion nicht, Andere dürfte sich aber auf einen anderen Autofahrer beziehen.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler https://www.dvr.de/presse/presseinformationen/laufen-lernen-dvr-und-bmvi-praesentieren-neue-autobahnplakate

Comment: @BernhardDöbler § 58(5) des amtlichen Regelwerkes des Rates für deutsche Rechtschreibung: "In folgenden Fällen schreibt man Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen klein, obwohl sie formale Merkmale der Substantivierung aufweisen [...] die folgenden Zahladjektive mit allen ihren Flexionsformen: _viel, wenig; (der, die, das) eine, (der, die, das) andere_ [...] Wenn der Schreibende zum Ausdruck bringen will, dass das Zahladjektiv substantivisch gebraucht ist, kann er es nach § 57(1) auch großschreiben [...]" https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6194#par58

Comment: Nach (guter) alter Rechtschreibung schreibt man *andere* immer klein (und zwar auch wenn es substantivisch verwendet wird). - Heute "darf" man's zwar auch groß schreiben, aber es gibt durchaus Leute - und darunter auch viele professionelle Schreiber - die die alte Schreibung vorziehen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/andere) darf andere alle drei grammatischen Geschlechter haben und *kann* aber muss nicht groß geschrieben werden, wenn es als Substantiv verwendet wird.

```
Bei Substantivierung ist auch Großschreibung möglich D 77, beispielsweise:

der, die, das and[e]re oder And[e]re
```

Das Geschlecht ist hier dasselbe wie das des durch "andere" ersetzte Wort.

> die andere [Frau/Farbe/...]
>
> der andere [Mann/Baum/...]
>
> das andere [Kind/Auto/...]

Comment: Ich finde den letzten Satz nicht optimal. Das grammatische Geschlecht hängt davon ab, was mit *andere* gemeint sein soll. Falls ein Kind gemeint ist, wäre auch Neutrum in Ordnung.  (Dass der Autor das festlegt, ist für die grammatikalische Frage ohne Belang.)

Answer (score 2):

Zur Frage der Vollständigkeit: Es handelt sich jeweils um Nebensätze als Antwortsätze auf eine Frage wie "Warum kam es (überhaupt) zu dem Unfall?" Die (pronominal realisierte) Nominalphrase "der/die andere" bezeichnet den Unfallgegner. Offensichtlich ist es möglich, dass die Rezipienten der Plakatserie diese und weitere Informationen - z.B. die Kette 'Armprothese > Autounfall' - sofort mitverstehen und stillschweigend ergänzen.

Comment: Wenn es sich um Plakate an einer Autobahn handelt, würde ich dieses Verstehen/Ergänzen nicht nur für möglich halten, sondern sogar als sicher unterstellen.

Comment: @Volker Landgraf: Natürlich. Ich hatte mein '_offensichtlich ist es möglich_' als Ausdruck der Verwunderung darüber gemeint, dass ein Plakat'betrachter' die fehlenden Kontexte, zumal beim Vorbeizischen auf der Autobahn, in nullkommanichts ergänzt und z.B. den (!) 'anderen' sofort als Unfallverursacher und damit Verantwortlichen für die Behinderung des 'Sprechers' erkennt, der ja auch wieder nicht als Sprecher dargestellt ist. Vielleicht versteht es auch nicht jeder sofort, und wahrscheinlich 'funktionieren' die Plakate nur an der Autobahn gut.